# to get next date

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I have a field `next_repay_date` as `varchar2(11)`.

I need to get the date after 2 days.

Suppose I am having next_repay_date as `25-Sep-2011` as `varchar2(11)`, I should get a result as `27-Sep-2011`

Please suggest a solution?

Comment: I've retagged it as Oracle, as she stated that in a deleted answer.

Comment: if you want to do date calculations, store the dates as actual dates

Answer (score 4):

Dates should not be held in char fields - use a Date or datetime

Then add two days - which I think is DBMS sepcific

Answer (score 3):

Step 1, use the correct type for dates, that is, type DATE.

Step 2, use yourdate + INTERVAL 2 DAY (mysql).

Comment: It's `INTERVAL '2' DAY` in Oracle.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using Oracle this could be done as

```
SELECT to_date('25-Sep-2007', 'dd-MON-RRRR') + 2 from dual
```

Answer (score 3):

Date arithmetic is really simply in Oracle, providing we have an actual DATE to work with.  So the first step is to cast your column to a DATE datatype, and then you can add or subtract days from it.

```
SQL> select to_date('27-SEP-2011', 'DD-MON-YYYY') + 2
  2  from dual
  3  /

TO_DATE('
---------
29-SEP-11

SQL>
```